# Как передать преобразованную дату?

Tags: python, django

Есть views

```
res = SSwAlive.objects.filter(is_deleted=0)
return render_to_response('test.html',{'res':res})
```

Данные в res

```
 id: 38
 sw: test
 ctime: 1317192076
 utime: 1317194473
 is_deleted: 0
```

Как передать преобразованную дату в test.html? Я так понимаю, можно и так

```
def dd(res):
h = []
for j in for res:
   h.append("{0}".format(datetime.fromtimestamp(j[1])))
return h
```

Может как-то можно проще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему не хотите написать дополнительный метод типа `time_from_time_stamp` к модели, который и будет возвращать нормальный datetime объект (или что вам нужно) из timestamp?
Типа:

```
MyModel(models.Model):
   field1 = ....

   def time_from_time_stamp(self)  
      return datetime.fromtimestamp(self.utime)
```

Тогда и в шаблоне, и в коде будете обращаться к нему также, как и к остальным полям:

```
ssw = SSwAlive.objects.get(is_deleted=0, ..., ...)
some_var = ssw.time_from_time_stamp
```

Comment: я хочу, только дельных проектов на django не делал, а необходимо переписать. так сказать консультируюсь.

Comment: :) Это не Джанго по сути, просто обычный метод Питоновского класса. Менеджер возвращает вам обычные экземпляры класса, описанный вами как Django-модель, так почему к ним просто не прилепить метод?:)

Comment: я уже прилепил метод и все красиво получается)

Comment: (Мелочь, но) `some_var = ssw.time_from_time_stamp` — не будет оно так работать. Или `ssw.time_from_time_stamp()` или `@property` перед `def`.

Answer (score 1):

Красивее всего сделать не методом у модели, а [реализовать свое поле](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-a-field-subclass). Тогда конверсия между UNIX timestamp и datetime будет прозрачной. См., например, [Using MYSQL's Unix Timestamp fields with Django](http://ianrolfe.livejournal.com/36017.html)

Comment: Интересное решение, спасибо! Взял на заметку.